# Subclass from a Superclass with no default constructor, without calling any other constructors

Tags: c++, class

I have a pretty basic problem but I can't find an acceptable solution (story of my life):

I would like to make a small change to a class' constructor, so I made a subclass, call it `sub`, of the superclass `super`. When constructing sub, I don't want to call any of the real constructors of `super`, but `super` *doesn't* have a default constructor.

Editing the `super` class to add a default constructor is a possibility, but it would involve editing a library that's frequently updated, which is its own can of worms.

What would you guys advise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the base class does not provides any default constructor, there is no way to define derived class without calling any of the constructors available.

Answer (score 1):

When you derive from a parent class, or even use that class as a private member of your class through composition, you're stuck with the public interface that the parent class provides.

So if you're not happy with the constructors that the base class provides, you need to either modify the base class implementation or re-write it as a new class adding whatever interface modifications you would want.

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 you can use constructor inheritance to make your life a little bit easier:

```
class super
{
public:
  super( int x );
  // more constructors
};

class sub : public super
{
  using super::super; // now all constructors is here
};
```

In the code above `sub::sub(int)` is automatically defined as `sub::sub(int x) : super(x) {}` so you do not need to write constructors in `sub` manually.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, what you want (subclass to call the parent class's default constructor when there isn't one) isn't possible.

However, what you could do is add a *protected* default constructor to the parent class. This wouldn't alter the public interface for other library users, but would allow subclasses to call it.

Comment: The library isn't my own, and I'm required to kept the most up to date version to comply with the rules of the FIRST Robotics Competition. Everytime it changes I'd have to remember to amend it, quite a bother :(